# Error opening txt file in arduino dataloger script

Tags: arduino

Here is my code. I cannot print data to my SD card because the txt file fails to open.
It worked the very first time I ran my code and has not worked since. Now I receive the "error opening test.txt" message in my serial port.

I am not fluent in any computer languages and most of this is copy past code from examples and online research. I am trying to execute something fairly simple. I want to collect the data from an accelerometer and save it to an SD card.

```cpp
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

const int MPU = 0x68;
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ, Tmp, GyX, GyY, GyZ;

const int chipSelect = 10;

void setup()
{
    Wire.begin();
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
    Wire.write(0x6B);
    Wire.write(0);
    Wire.endTransmission(true);
    //pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    //set up sensor
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
    Wire.write(0x3B);
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 12, true);
    AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    GyX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    GyY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
    GyZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();

    //print to serial port
    Serial.println(AcX);
    Serial.println(AcY);
    Serial.println(AcZ);
    Serial.println(GyX);
    Serial.println(GyY);
    Serial.println(GyZ);

    Serial.println(" ");
    delay(333);

    //print to SD card
    File dataFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    // if the file is available, write to it:
    if (dataFile) {
        dataFile.println(AcX);
        dataFile.println(AcY);
        dataFile.println(AcZ);
        dataFile.println(GyX);
        dataFile.println(GyY);
        dataFile.println(GyZ);
        dataFile.close();

        delay(333);
    }
    // if the file isn't open, pop up an error:
    else {
        Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize the SD. Compare to your examples. Feel free to answer this question yourself.

Comment: note this datalog tag is not the datalog tag you are looking for [waves hand]  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog